# Designer Error in WPF application

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Whenever I add external WPF Toolkit(e.g. BusyIndicator), designer fails.

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SfuI.jpg) to see the error screenshot.
Is there any solution for this?

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Ksg.jpg) is the XAML.

Comment: @AnkurTripathi - Pls refer to edit.

Comment: After remove <wpfx:busyindicator>  its working?

Comment: Yes, it works when I remove busyindicator tag.

Comment: Show me busyindicator xaml file

Comment: Refer to 'Edit' in the question. That's all of the XAML I have used.

Comment: what is busyindicator  and why you using this?

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal: Which VS version are you using? I'm using the same `BusyIndicator` implementation in one of my projects. In VS2012 the designer is working. If I recall it correctly, it was not working in VS2008.

Comment: @DHN - I am using VS2010.

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal: Well, I don't have a VS2010 to test it, but I guess it's the same there as in VS2008. Two options: 1.) Live with it and without the designer, which is actually not needed, IMHO. I'm sure that you've already tried to start your application. 2.) Upgrade to at least VS2012 if possible. [3.) Spend a lot of time to fix the issue, which is not known whether it's possible.]

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal: Well I forgot about another option. 4.) Depending on which version of WpfToolkit you're using. Try to find a later version. This might provide you full Designer support.

Comment: Already applied 1, 3 and 4 ;).. I think its time for option 2 now. Thanks!!

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal You're welcome.